# how to convert query php to laravel framework

Tags: laravel

how can I convert this query to Laravel query

```
SELECT * FROM dbx_a 
WHERE date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW() AND name = 'MANAGEMENT' 
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: By reading the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries

Answer (score 0):

you can use [carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) to help you building your query:

```
 $beforeThirtyDay = Carbon::now()->subDays(30);
 DB::table('dbx_a')->select('*')->whereBetween('date', array(Carbon::now(), $beforeThirtyDay))
            ->where('name', '=', 'MANAGEMENT')->orderByDesc('date')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```php
DB::table('dbx_a')
  ->whereRaw('date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()')
  ->where('name', 'MANAGEMENT')
  ->orderByDesc('date')
  ->get();
```